# How do you add an exclusion for emails on the default email app or Outlook that are important when Do Not Disturb is enabled?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, ms-office, do-not-disturb

iOS 12 has a `Do Not Disburb` functionality that when turned on does not notify you of emails; but some emails are important, so is there an exclusion list for certain email addresses so that they do wake you up while the `Do Not Disturb` functionality is enabled?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish here. From what do you want to exclude these emails, and based on what criteria? Do you refer to the VIP functionality of Apple Mail, or something from Outlook? Are you looking for a solution on macOS or on iOS?

Comment: Just guessing here, he is trying to replicate the feature in do not disturb where PHONE CALLS will get through if they are in your favorites list, only with Emails.